# Packages not working, using Anaconda

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda for Windows. It's on my work PC, so I chose the option "Just for Me" as I don't have admin rights.

Anaconda is installed on the following directory:

```
c:\Users\huf069\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda
```

The Windows installer has added this directory (+ the Anaconda\Scripts directory) to the System path.

I can launch Python but trying to run
 `x = randn(100,100)` 
gives me a `Name Error: name 'randn' is not defined`, 
whereas, as I understood, this command should work when using Anaconda, as the numpy package is included.

it works fine if I do:

```
import numpy
numpy.random.randn(100,100)
```

Anyone understand what could be happening ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I can launch Python, but trying to run `x = randn(100,100)` gives me a `Name Error: name 'randn' is not defined`, whereas, as I understood, this command should work when using Anaconda, as the `numpy` package is included

The *Anaconda* distribution comes with the `numpy` package included, but still you'll need to *import* the package. If you want to use the `randn()` function without having to call the complete name, you can import it to your local namespace:

```
from numpy.random import randn
x = randn(100,100)
```

Otherwise, the call `numpy.random.randn` is your way to go.

You might want tot take a look at the [Modules section](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) of the Python Tutorial.

Comment: OK thanks Finwood ! ... , I was confused by the tutorial I was following (from Kevin Sheppard) in which he says to enter successfully the following commands: "randn", "mean",  "plot" and that if all dependencies are correctly installed, then results should be displayed ... not mentioning any "import" ....