# Am I importing a package from conda wrong in my python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package, conda

**Heyo!** I know this may look like a duplicate question of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516319/packages-not-working-using-anaconda), but there is a little difference. I want to import the whole package, not just one or a groups of functions. When I import packages from Anaconda, and try to import them into a python script, I get `ErrorModuleNotFound`. I might be importing this wrong, so here is the information:

- I am using `Python 3.6` and `conda 4.3.21`.
- Anaconda packages can be found in this directory: `C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3`
- What I put into the Anaconda Prompt: `pip install wikipedia` *(It installed successfully...)*
- Directory of my Python Script: `C:\Users\aglin\Desktop\test.py`
- Conda env list: `root                  *  C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3`
- Path of Python.exe `C:\Users\aglin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe` and `C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\python.exe`

What my Python Script contains:

```
import wikipedia
print (wikipedia.summary("Windows OS"))
win = wikipedia.page("New York")
win.content
```

Error I'm getting:

```
================== RESTART: C:\Users\aglin\Desktop\test.py ==================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aglin\Desktop\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import wikipedia
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wikipedia'
```

**My question:** How can I import the package `wikipedia` without getting this error? If it helps, "Wikipedia API for Python's Documentation" can be found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wikipedia/). Also, I'm pretty new to Python, so if I need to do anything specific or look at documentation, please tell me. Thanks! :D

Comment: When you installed wikipedia had you activated the Py36 environment? And when you opened the Python script had you activated that same environment?

Comment: Like I said, I'm new to Python. Can you please tell me what that means? xD

Comment: Can you enter `conda env list`, please, and put result in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the usual steps to create an environment in conda, putting a version of Python into it, and importing a library into it afterwards.

The steps are:

- conda create --name Py36 python=3.6
- activate Py36
- pip install wikipedia

You will notice that, at the end of the display, it's possible to open the Python interpreter and import wikipedia.

---

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.125]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\scratch>conda create --name Py36 python=3.6
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\Py36:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    certifi:        2017.11.5-py36hb8ac631_0
    pip:            9.0.1-py36h226ae91_4
    python:         3.6.3-h3b118a2_4
    setuptools:     36.5.0-py36h65f9e6e_0
    vc:             14-h2379b0c_2
    vs2015_runtime: 14.0.25123-hd4c4e62_2
    wheel:          0.30.0-py36h6c3ec14_1
    wincertstore:   0.2-py36h7fe50ca_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

#
# To activate this environment, use:
# > activate Py36
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use:
# > deactivate
#
# * for power-users using bash, you must source
#


C:\scratch>activate Py36

(Py36) C:\scratch>pip install wikipedia
Collecting wikipedia
Collecting beautifulsoup4 (from wikipedia)
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0 (from wikipedia)
  Using cached requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0->wikipedia)
  Using cached urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.7,>=2.5 (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0->wikipedia)
  Using cached idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\programdata\miniconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0->wikipedia)
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0->wikipedia)
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: beautifulsoup4, urllib3, idna, chardet, requests, wikipedia
Successfully installed beautifulsoup4-4.6.0 chardet-3.0.4 idna-2.6 requests-2.18.4 urllib3-1.22 wikipedia-1.4.0

(Py36) C:\scratch>python
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Nov  8 2017, 15:10:56) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wikipedia
>>> ^Z


(Py36) C:\scratch>
```

Comment: Thanks Bill. However; when I open IDLE and try to import Wikipedia, the same error of `ErrorModuleNotFound` appears. I went through all your steps perfectly with no errors.

Comment: Works on my machine!

Comment: I don't know what to suggest.

Comment: Are you on Win64 and, if so, do intermediate results appear similar to mine?

Comment: The only thing that is different is that the packages under setuptools don't show up when created a new enviroment. I am indeed using Win64...

Comment: I re-installed python and anaconda, and it somehow worked. Thanks for the help Bill! :D

Comment: I once hired someone to do sys admin and that was one of her frequently used remedies. It horrified me at first but eventually I realised it can be the best way out of a bad situation. Anyway, you're welcome.

Comment: `wikipedia` seems to be available on the conda-forge channel, so you should be able to install it with `conda install -c conda-forge wikipedia`. That has the advantage that future `conda` commands e.g. `conda update` will be aware of the package.